# Does R's package support unicode rd file?

Tags: r

My platform is:

```
Win7 64
Rtudio
R3.1.3
devtools 1.8.0
Rxygen2 4.1.1
```

I am trying to make a package of my own. I need to describe the function by unicode. I used Roxygen2 to generate the Rd file. The code is very simple(I removed the real function just know how to make a package):

xxxx means comment made by unicode.

```
#' eastChoice
#' @param fn.kind wind xxxxxx
#' @param estChoice.Path wind
#' @return data.frame
#' @export
#' @examples
#' getIndByEastChoice("20150108.csv")
getIndByEastChoice <- function(fn.kind){
  d <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,3), b=c(4,5,6))
  dt <- data.table::data.table(d)
}
```

When I check(devtools) the R code, it always failed. The following error information is given:

```
* checking PDF version of manual ... WARNING
LaTeX errors when creating PDF version.
This typically indicates Rd problems.
LaTeX errors found:
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:��<87> not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
```

At first I thought that the Roxygen2 does not support unicode other than ASCII, but I read the Rd file generated by Roxygen2, it is OK. 
And then I just use build&Reload function(using devtools), to my suprise, it passed.

And then I add more unicode comment in the R file and checked(devtools) it again. It is like the following:

```
#' eastChoice xxxxxx
#' @param fn.kind wind xxxxx
#' @param estChoice.Path wind xxxxxxxx
#' @return data.frame xxxxxxx
#' @export
#' @examples
#' getIndByEastChoice("20150108.csv")
getIndByEastChoice <- function(fn.kind){
  d <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,3), b=c(4,5,6))
  dt <- data.table::data.table(d)
}
```

It failed as I expected, but other information was given and seems more serious:

```
* checking whether package 'ftools.temp' can be installed ... ERROR
Installation failed.
See 'D:/onedrive/program/R.package/ftools.temp.Rcheck/00install.out' for details.
```

So I checked the log:

```
* installing *source* package 'ftools.temp' ...
** R
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
wrong in gsub("&", "&amp;", x, fixed = TRUE) : '<86>'multi byte string is wrong
* removing 'D:/onedrive/program/R.package/ftools.temp.Rcheck/ftools.temp'
```

And this time build&load also failed.

So I think that maybe the R does not support unicode other ASCII in its RD file? Can any one confirm it? If it is true, I will not waste my time trying to solve this problem.

---

@hrbrmstr
Thank you. I have tried your advice. First, I added the line "Encoding:UTF-8" in the decription file,  and then saved .R and DESCRIPTION with coding UTF-8 to ensure that the encode is correct. And I run the "check " function, but I got the same error:

```
strsplit(txt, "\n", fixed = TRUE)���о���: �������ַ���1����UTF-8
* checking examples ... OK
* checking PDF version of manual ... WARNING
LaTeX errors when creating PDF version.
This typically indicates Rd problems.
����: ��������'"D:/R/R-31~1.3/bin/x64/Rcmd.exe" Rd2pdf  --batch --no-preview --build-dir="C:/Users/kanpu/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpgFjyKw/Rd2pdf15f2c22b7768d" --no-clean -o  ftools.temp-manual.pdf  "D:/onedrive/program/R.package/ftools.temp.Rcheck/ftools.temp"'��״̬��1
LaTeX errors found:
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:��<97> not set up for use with LaTeX.
```

The DESCRIPTION is like this:

```
Package: ftools.temp
Type: Package
Title: Just try to make a package
Version: 0.1
Date: 2015-08-25
Author: None
Maintainer: no one <none@somewhere.net>
Description: Just try to make a package
License: CPL
LazyData: TRUE
Encoding:UTF-8
Depends:
  data.table
```

Comment: Try adding `Encoding: UTF-8`  into the `DESCRIPTION` file and re-documenting & re-building & re-checking the pkg.

Comment: Any more news on this?